# Date comparison in query not matching when the cells being compared are date but works if cells are made into text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sample sheet for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1XTAFzI1-M0zJZtKiBviSfohXcqbzaPEnxHlQ4zDSU/edit?usp=sharing

Im trying to compare one date cell to a column of date cells. I am using the query function to list out all the matching rows. Specifically I am comparing the date column in Call Log Details sheet to the date cell B2 in the EOD sheet. When I make both the column and cell in the 2 sheets to be formatted into mm/dd/yy, the function doesnt work. But when I make both the column and the cell in the 2 sheets to be formatted into Plain Text, the function works and displays the rows. I cant have the column in the Call Log Details to be Plain Text since I am adding a calendar and will be doing calculations using dates. How am I able to make the comparison to work with at least the column being a date value and if possible also the cell?

Here is the formula I am using to output the rows found in the EOD sheet at cell B2:

`=query('Call Log Details'!A2:X," select T where A = '"&B1&"' order by A,B,D",0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query understands dates only in this format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

use:

```
=QUERY('Call Log Details'!A2:X,
 "select T 
  where A = date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  order by A,B,D", 0)
```

[image]

---

### suggestion for column T:

```
={"RESERVED!!!"; ARRAYFORMULA(
 {IF('Call Log Details'!E2:E="",,CHAR(10)&
 "DATE : "&TEXT('Call Log Details'!A2:A+'Call Log Details'!B2:B, "m/d/yy h:m AM/PM")&CHAR(10)& 
 "PT: "&'Call Log Details'!D2:D&CHAR(10)&
 "FROM: "&'Call Log Details'!E2:E&CHAR(10)& 
 "RELATION TO PATIENT: "&'Call Log Details'!F2:F&CHAR(10)&
 "CALL BACK# "&'Call Log Details'!G2:G&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)& 
 "MESSAGE.: "&CHAR(10)&'Call Log Details'!J2:J&CHAR(10))})}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so the 2 important takeaways for me for this situation is that I need to add the word "date"after the "=" sign and also convert the dates into the "yyyy-mm-dd". Thank you very much, the code is working perfectly!

Comment: @googlesheettest yes, that's right. answer updated

Comment: oh yes good catch, that was only working before because my column A was in text format. Thank you very much for bringing that up. you've been very helpful!